# CodeIgniter - escaping values before inserting in database - single quotes issue

Tags: codeigniter, escaping, quotes

I am having issue with inserting value in database. Somehow my value gets wrapped by single quotes. Value is escaped just in order, though.

Sample of value: **Test " ' test**

Sample of value inserted in db: **'Test \" \' test'**

I am using Active Record:

```
$data = array(
    'some_value' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('some_value')),
    ...

$this->db->insert('some_table', $data);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong? When you retrieve the value from database and display it in HTML format, Is it wrong?

Comment: I did not output it as HTML (and probably never will, I am just collecting data in database). When I am looking in the database table, I see value wrapped in single quotes.